# Kendo Grid Read data with parameters that comes NULL for a some reasons

Tags: javascript, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using the following code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Orders)
  .Name("gridOrders")
  .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.Date).Title("Date");
          columns.Bound(p => p.Reference).Title("Reference");
          columns.Bound(p => p.Products).Title("Product(s)");
          columns.Bound(p => p.Customer).Title("Customer");
          columns.Bound(p => p.ServiceName).Title("Service");
          columns.Bound(p => p.OrderTotal).Title("Order total");
      })
  .Pageable()
  .Sortable()
  .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(400))
  .Filterable()
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
      .Model(model => model.Field(x => x.Reference).Editable(false))
      .Model(model => model.Field(x => x.OrderTotal).Editable(false))
      .Model(model => model.Field(x => x.Date).Editable(false))
      .Model(model => model.Field(x => x.ServiceName).Editable(false))
      .Model(model => model.Field(x => x.Products).Editable(false))
      .Model(model => model.Field(x => x.Customer).Editable(false))
      .PageSize(10)
      .ServerOperation(true)
      //.Read(read => read.Action("GetOrders", "Dashboard", new { datex = "lalala" } ))
      .Read(read => read.Action("GetOrders", "Dashboard").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("getValues"))
  ))
```

As you see getValues JavaScript function used. What I have in this function:

```
<script>
function getValues() {
    return {
        datex: "2012/12/12" // $("#dates").data("kendoDropDownList").value()
    };
}
</script>
```

In controller code I got datex parameter as NULL:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetOrders([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string datex)
    {...}
```

I have no any ideas why that's happen... Docs told me that all must be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your Kendo UI version ?

As mentionned on [this thread](http://www.telerik.com/forums/permalink/HiPpCy1WfUG_1rb3Ooc8vQ) :

> There is a known issue regarding the sending of additional data parameters in Q3 SP1 release i.e. version 2013.3.1316.

Maybe you just have to upgrade your version.